# Assembler Двойное слово умножение

Tags: ассемблер

у меня есть знаковое двойное слово после умножения ax,bx и в ax находится на данный момент двойное слово, мне нужно умножить двойное слово на 2 как это сделать просто написать imul 2?

Comment: "_в ax находится на данный момент двойное слово_", оно не может там находится, регистр ax размером 16 бит, т.е. в одинарное слово. И если вы уже что то умножали, то зачем еще раз умножать, можно в предыдущий раз умножить на в 2 раза больший множитель

Comment: А еще imul http://asmworld.ru/spravochnik-komand/imul/ умеет умножать двойные слова только с использованием 32 битных регистров (eax). И умножение на 2 проще заменить сдвигом влево на 1 бит